# Django FileField not including uploaded file in form output request

Tags: python, html, django, filefield

I am having trouble getting access to a simple uploaded file which I need to parse without saving it. Since the file does not need to be saved I have not made a model for it. All other threads on this state the html form encoding type, name tag are the primary reasons why request.FILES is not appearing-- I have addressed these and still there is no request.FILES being captured.

**forms.py**

```
class DataExportForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a template',help_text='Extracted info will be returned')
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

<tr><th><label for="id_docfile">Select a template:</label></th><td><input id="id
_docfile" name="docfile" type="file" />
<button type="submit" name="action">Upload</button>
<br /><span class="helptext">Zip file wil
l be returned with data</span></td></tr>   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method=='POST':        
    form=DataExportForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        #Code runs OK till here but request.FILES does not exist. 
        groupList=extractTemplateNames(request.FILES['file'].read())
```

I guess if I get it working I may find the file not in request.FILES['file'] but in request.FILES['docfile'] but at this point request.FILES does not exist. Any tips to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, problem is just that you are trying to access file using wrong name. Field on form has name  `docfile`. Same name it will have in `request.FILES` array.

Possibly, you simply misunderstood an error message saying that there is no `file` in `FILES`.

And `form.is_valid` access FILES array correctly, that is why form is considered to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the only thing missing was looking for request.FILES['docfile']

not request.FILES['file'] . It works! Hope this is helpful to someone